# Repeating cells while parsing XML data using swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, tableview

I am trying to parse some xml data in a tableview custom cell but the cells are repeating 7 times before a new one different cell comes, and repeating again...

the xml code:

```
<Person>
<Table>
    <id>129</id>
    <name>Peter</name>
    <url>http://www.peter.com</url>
    <age>30</age>
    <city>London</city>
    <img>http://img.peter.com/341.jpg</img>
</Table>
<Table>
    <id>156</id>
    <name>Alfred</name>
    <url>http://www.alfred.com</url>
    <age>34</age>
    <city>New York</city>
    <img>http://img.alfred.com/388.jpg</img>
</Table>
<Table>
    <id>159</id>
    <name>Chris</name>
    <url>http://www.chris.com</url>
    <age>37</age>
    <city>Paris</city>
    <img>http://img.chris.com/568.jpg</img>
</Table>
```

I want show only the Id, Name and City in the tableview. Before parse from url the code was working properly, of course with some modified parts...

the swift code:

```
func parsingDataFromUrl(){
    array = []
    parser = NSXMLParser(contentsOfURL: NSURL(string:"http://www.somexmldata.com")!)!
    parser.delegate = self
    parser.parse()
    tableView.reloadData() 
}    

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, foundCharacters string: String) {
    if element.isEqualToString("id"){
        uiId.appendString(string)
    }
    else if element.isEqualToString("name"){
        uiName.appendString(string)
    }
    else if element.isEqualToString("city"){
        uiCity.appendString(string)
    }
}    

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didStartElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?, attributes attributeDict: [String : String]) {
    element = elementName
    if (elementName as NSString).isEqualToString("Table"){
        elements = NSMutableDictionary()
        elements = [:]         
        uiName = NSMutableString()
        uiName = ""
        uiId = NSMutableString()
        uiId = ""
        uiCity = NSMutableString()
        uiCity = ""        
    }
}    

func parser(parser: NSXMLParser, didEndElement elementName: String, namespaceURI: String?, qualifiedName qName: String?) {

    if (!uiId.isEqual(nil)){
        elements.setObject(uiId, forKey: "id")
    }
    if (!uiName.isEqual(nil)){
        elements.setObject(uiName, forKey: "name")
    }
    if (!uiCity.isEqual(nil)){
        elements.setObject(uiCity, forKey: "city")
    }
    array.addObject(elements)
}    

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return array.count
}   

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    if (cell.isEqual(NSNull)){
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("cell", owner: self, options:nil)[0] as! CustomCell
    }
    cell.uiId.text = array.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("id") as! NSString as String
    cell.uiName.text = array.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("name") as! NSString as String
    cell.uiCity.text = array.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row).valueForKey("city") as! NSString as String
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You are reusing the cell. Make sure you clear the cell elements before assigning new values. Casting to NSString and them to String makes no sense.

Comment: like `elements = [:]` after `array.addObject(elements)` ?

Comment: The cell uiId.text, uiName.text, uiCity.text, etc..

Comment: @Lsdabus Does not work